# Let $a,b\in G$. If $a^{4}b=ba$ and $a^{3}=e$, then prove that $ab=ba$.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, abelian-groups

Can someone tell me whether my solution is incorrect or too short?

> Let $a,b\in G$. If $a^{4}b=ba$ and $a^{3}=e$, then prove that $ab=ba$.

$ab =aeb=aa^{3}b=a^{4}b=ba$ is all I did so far. Is it too short or incorrect logically?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Thank you for taking the time to look at it and answer. :)

Comment: I like it.  Direct and straight from point A to point B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is good and correct, but the reverse order seems clearer to me:
$$
ba = a^{4}b = a^3ab = eab = ab
$$

Comment: I agree, I did the reverse order at first to figure out where to go. I just started from $ab$ afterwards to make it look more nicer.

Answer (score 2):

That's correct.

An easier way to think about it once you are used to actions by conjugation is that $a=ea=a^3a=a^4=bab^{-1}$ and thus $ab=ba$.  Your proof is just as good, though.